# Getting array as input of array while trying to input a single value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

In the below case I am trying to put a single value from a multiple select options. If I select multiple value I get is as an array instead of 3 values and even for a single value I am getting an array as input dues to which in the display I see the values as in the screenshot. for every country there can be n number of friends so the placecollection array has 2 keys
Place and locfrnd.
so I am taking an input from multiple select and want that to appear as single inputs even when multiple values are selected

```
else if (frnd_exist == 0) {
    var frnds = [];
    alert("friend does not exist");
    var secondName = $scope.Friend;

    if (frnd_i == 0) {
        frnd_i = $scope.placeCollection[cnt_i].locFrnd.length;
    }

    $scope.placeCollection[cnt_i].locFrnd[frnd_i] = {
        name: secondName
    };

}
```

[image]

Comment: Change `var secondName = $scope.Friend;` to `var secondName = $scope.Friend[0];`?